# Who is this character, wearing a space suit with a big hole in the upper torso?

Tags: comics, character-identification

I saw a [tweet](https://twitter.com/kateleth/status/370271698656198656) today which probably represents the most ridiculous take on the [Chainmail Bikini](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChainmailBikini) trope I've ever seen.

[image]

Even as simple armor, this wouldn't pass the practicality test with such exposure. But what's worse is that it actually appears to be a *space suit*! (Note what appears to be an air tube leading from the helmet to a tank on her back.) This was pointed out in a rather amusing reply:

[image]

Can anyone identify the character in this picture, and/or the comic of origin? Is there any explanation given in-universe for this otherwise impractical exposure?

Comment: For what it’s worth, assuming the seal on the head was sufficient to maintain normal pressure on her mouth and nostrils (so she can breathe), a vacuum applied only to her chest wouldn’t really be *that* problematic, even if it were actually exposed. Painful and uncomfortable, but not life-threatening. Human skin is strong enough to more-or-less maintain pressurization of the body’s internals even in a hard vacuum. Add in super-strength and super-endurance and it’s conceivable that it might not even be uncomfortable or debilitating.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**I can identify the hero. That is [Spider-Woman](http://marvel.com/universe/Spider-Woman_%28Jessica_Drew%29). Here is another clip from the same comic. What looks like skin is actually her skin-tight costume with bad coloring. The comic is Avengers #18.**

[image]

> Jessica Drew possesses superhuman strength (can lift at least up to 7 tons), endurance and speed. She can focus her bioelectric energy into "venom blasts" sufficient to stun or kill normal humans, and she can also adhere to almost any surface. Jessica rapidly forms an immunity to all poisons and drugs, and is totally immune to radiation. **Marvel Wiki: [Spider-Woman](http://marvel.com/universe/Spider-Woman_%28Jessica_Drew%29#ixzz2cdbdjfNZ)**

Comment: So, her costume also doubles as a pressure suit?

Comment: Her costume was designed by the villainous agency [HYDRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HYDRA) and was considered a state of the art piece of technology which theoretically could double as a pressure suit...

Comment: Is that Hulk behind her?

Comment: @Monty129: Could be Hulk.  Outfit looks more like Cyborg, but Cyborg is DC and Spiderwoman is Marvel.  He's build like Absorbing Man, but has hair and doesn't appear to be a villain.  Based on build and coloration, I can't think of a more likely person than Hulk.

Comment: Yes. There are 18 Avengers along in this particular event. The Hulk is on the cover in that suit and haircut. [See these images](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/JoshWildingNewsAndReviews/news/?a=85580). Looking at others images of this exo-protective gear, the open window region appears to be a way to identify people because all of the Humans who are there end up wearing something like it even if they don't need to worry about the environment.

Comment: It should also be noted that these aren't so much "space suits" as modular "space armor" placed onto certain areas - the torso isn't the only exposed area. It's more like an exo-suit than a contained spacesuit.